# Get caret position

Tags: input, click, coordinates, textarea, caret

Is it possible to get the caret position in pixels relative to the window. I need to get the caret position by space or by pressing the arrows. The thought arises whether it is possible to simulate a mouse click (since a mouse click has properties of the click coordinate) by pressing a space (that is, in a text field by pressing the space, the position of the caret changes), any ideas? This is necessary in order to position the block with a hint near the entered word. I managed to do this only by clicking the mouse, since I can get its coordinates

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What's the context of your question? A website, an X11 or Windows program, or something else?

Comment: The context is Web-development using JavaScript.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant details in the post already, see also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).